# Why is my toilet backing up and bubbling after replacing an ejector pump?

Tags: toilet, drain-waste-vent, sewer

About two weeks ago my sewage ejector pump died and had a massive overflow in the basement. I replaced the pump but I am now noticing that the toilet backs up. I am also noticing that when I take a shower the toilet bubbles.

Any clue???

Answer (score 1):

You have a clog downstream of the pump most likely.  It might have even died because of this (overheated?).

You will need a drain auger/snake in order to clear this.  If it's close to your access point you might be able to use a small handheld one, but most likely you'll need an electric drum snake:

[image: Electric Drum Snake]

You can rent these from most home improvement stores.